# How to extract Time from a SRT File?

Tags: python, srt

I'am a newbie in python and i want help in extracting the Start and End time from a SRT File of a movie for my project.

Example:

```
1

00:00:39,330 --> 00:00:41,958

Things are never gonna be
the same now.

2

00:00:42,125 --> 00:00:44,169

I mean, look at this.

3

00:00:44,336 --> 00:00:46,379

You got aliens.
```

I want to Extract the Start time(00:00:39) and End time(00:00:41) and the text(Things are never gonna be
the same now.) Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using an existing library, such as https://pypi.org/project/srt/ for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract start time, end time and text like below:

```
import pysrt
subs = pysrt.open(file_path)           # Fetch subtitles from the SRT file
for sub in subs:
     text = sub.text                 # Extract Text
     start_time = sub.start          # Extract Start Time Stamb
     end_time = sub.end              # Extract End Time Stamb
```